# Build some files, copy the rest

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I have a very simple project. I have some bash files, and some JavaScript files in a `src/` directory, I want to transpile the JS files, and copy the rest.

Here's my folder structure:

```
root
 |- dist // Where grunt should output
 |- src
 |   |- run_code  // this is a bash file calling `code`
 |   |- code.es6  // My JavaScript files
 |
 |- Gruntfile.js
 |- package.json
```

---

So at the moment I have a Gruntfile which calls `babel` which transpiles my `.es6` files to `.js`, but unfortunately, my bash file, `run_code` isn't transpiled. Here's my gruntfile:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

    grunt.initConfig({
        babel: {
            options: {
                presets: ['es2015'],
                plugins: []
            },
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: 'src/',
                    src: ['**/*.es6'],
                    dest: 'dist/',
                    ext: '.js'
                }]
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['babel']);
};
```

Take a look at the `files: [{` section. As you can see I'm compiling `.es6` files from the `src/` directory to the `dist/` directory. This works fine except **it doesn't copy `run_code`**.

I may add other tasks later but my question is, how should I go about copying files that have not been touched by grunt tasks yet? I know I might be able to do a filter copying all files that aren't `.es6`, but hardcoding feels like a very hacky solution, surely there should be some nice way to do this with grunt (if someone knows a way to copy and preserve permissions that would be even better).

Comment: Not enough time to answer ATM: I you want to copy files use the [`grunt-contrib-copy`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-copy#usage-examples) Plugin. Like nearly all paths configs it also accepts [`!` negations in the glob patterns](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns). The same goes for babel. You might add a negative file pattern to the set, e.g.: `{src: '!src/*.es6', dest: ...}` to exclude .es6 files from copy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As near as I can tell, `cwd` says we're copying from the `src/` directory and `src` says you only want `.es6` files. So you're not actually telling it to copy ("run through babel", really) `run_code`.

Rename `run_code` to `run_code.es6` or add it to the `src` array.

If you just want to copy `run_code` without trying to transcode it, use one of the `copy` packages. In the same way you included `babel`, add a package like [`grunt-contrib-copy`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-copy) to make a `copy` task available. Installation and usage are a lot like those for `babel`, quoted below for convenience:

Installing:

```
npm install grunt-contrib-copy --save-dev
```

To use, add:

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
```

And something like this to your `initConfig`:

```
copy: {
  main: {
    files: [
      {
        expand: true,
        cwd: 'src/',
        src: ['run_code'],
        dest: 'dist/'}
      }
    ],
  },
}
```

I'd also recommend sorting your `.es6` files and copy-able files into their own directories for organization and so you can take advantage of wildcard expressions.

Comment: Could you explain on how I would use the `copy` package well to do this task? Also, `run_file` is not a JavaScript file so I cannot rename it to `run_file.es6`.

Comment: @Downgoat Updated to take your comment into account.